# sudo apt-get xpra version confusion

Tags: apt, xpra

I have been trying to get my sysadmin to install xpra on our shared linux environment. Following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xpra), we used `apt-get xpra` to install a version of Xpra on the machine.

`xpra --version` returns

```
xpra v0.12.3
```

As the current stable version is 2.5.x, it seems that the version we get using apt-get is crazy old. Moreover, some dependencies (e.g. least python-gtkglext1, python-pil) seem not to be installed.

`cat /etc/os-release` shows the following info about my os version.

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Upon some googling, I found [this](https://www.xpra.org/trac/wiki/Packaging/DistributionPackages), which suggests that 0.12.3 is "dangerous" and that Ubuntu Trusty is no longer supported(?). I wonder if this information is up to date?

My question is: what is the easiest way to install the current version of Xpra on my machine (assuming that updating the OS is out of the question)?

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if there is any more info you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is accurate: Xpra 0.12.3 is very old, has a number of issues, and Ubuntu 14.04 is no longer supported unless [you have a support contract](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr).

To get an up-to-date version of Xpra, the *simplest* option is to upgrade to at least Ubuntu 16.04 (which is still supported without a support contract) and install Xpra from [Mikhail Novosyolov’s PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mikhailnov/+archive/ubuntu/utils):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/utils
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xpra
```

If you have to stay on Ubuntu 14.04, you’ll probably have to build Xpra from source.

Comment: Or use the official xpra.org packages:
https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Download